# How to pass the values of the textboxes(which are IN LOOP) from view to the controller with respect to the item id selected in the dropdown box?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net

I would like to pass the values of the multiple textboxes from view to the controller with respect to the item id selected in the dropdown box.

NOTE:-Multiple textboxes are produced because user can select multiple items from dropdown.

This is a part of my Controller:-

```
foreach(var data in propertyViewModel.PropertyInvestors)
    {
    FounderInvestment founderInvestment = new FounderInvestment
    {
        Id = propertyViewModel.FounderInvestmentViewModel.Id ?? 0,
        InstallmentPeriod = propertyViewModel.FounderInvestmentViewModel.InstallmentPeriod,
        InvestorId = Convert.ToInt32(data),
        PropertyId = property.Id,
        Investment = propertyViewModel.FounderInvestmentViewModel.Investment
    };
    _founderInvestmentQueryProcessor.Create(founderInvestment);
}
```

This is my dropdown:-

```
<div class="form-group">
  @Html.LabelFor(model => model.PropertyInvestors, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
  <div class="col-md-10">
    @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.PropertyInvestors, (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)@ViewBag.Investors, "Select", htmlAttributes: new {@id="dropdown", @class = "form-control",@multiple="multiple" })
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.PropertyInvestors, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
  </div>
</div>
```

These are the textboxes:-

```
<div id="showInvestmentForm" style="display:none">                        
    <div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.FounderInvestmentViewModel.Investment, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.FounderInvestmentViewModel.Investment, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.FounderInvestmentViewModel.Investment, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.FounderInvestmentViewModel.InstallmentPeriod, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.FounderInvestmentViewModel.InstallmentPeriod, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.FounderInvestmentViewModel.Investment, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>                       
</div>
```

This is the JS that produces the textboxes with respect to the number of dropdown items selected:-

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $("#dropdown").change(function () {
            var value = $(this).val();
            var form1 = $('#showInvestmentForm').html();
            if (value.length == 1) {
                $('#showInvestmentForm').show();
            }
            else if (value.length > 1) {
                for (var i = value.length; i <= value.length ; i++) {
                    $(form1).appendTo('#field1');
                }
            }
            else {
                $('#showInvestmentForm').hide();
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

PROBLEM:---- The problem that I am getting here is that the value of the first 'form-group' textboxes is being repeated for all the textboxes.i.e first entry is being repeated and passed to the controller.How do I solve this issue?

[This is how it gets saved in Founder Investment Database Table because of repeat](https://i.stack.imgur.com/emJzu.jpg)

Comment: Can you show an example of the resulting HTML form being incorrectly posted to the server after the JavaScript code has added more fields?  As well as the structure that the controller is using to read from the form?  (a model?  arguments to the constructor method?  directly from the form collection?)  Basically, what is the exact form being posted and what is the specific server-side value where you expect the input to be?

Comment: @David I added a screenshot of database table,take a look. I did not know how else to give you an example.The textboxes produced using the loop are becoming of no use as the same value from first boxes are being repeated.

Comment: It seems to me that value.length is not what you want. If this works, i guess, value is a string and value.length is the number of characters in this string. Then you repeat the html inside #showInvestmentForm for each character in value. Is this the expected behavior?

Comment: @SudeepShrestha: A screenshot of your database table isn't really the same thing as the resulting HTML on the page.  The point here is to do some debugging, not just look at the result and make guesses.  In your browser, when you're about to post the form, *what is the actual HTML* of that form?

Comment: @David the ID of all the produced textboxes are same. I dont know how to provide indexing to them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to Post back the values of those textboxes,You need indexing. In order to do that, first create a 'Dummy' code for those two input text boxes like this:--->

```
<div id="showInvestmentForm" style="display:none">                        
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="FounderInvestments.Investment" class="control-label col-md-2">Investment</label>
            <div class="col-md-10">
                <input type="number" name="FounderInvestments[#].Investment" value="" class="form-control" />
                <input type="hidden" name="FounderInvestments[#].Index" value="" />                    
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="FounderInvestments.InstallmentPeriod" class="control-label col-md-2">Installment Period</label>
            <div class="col-md-10">
                <input type="number" name="FounderInvestments[#].InstallmentPeriod" value="" class="form-control" />                        
            </div>
        </div>                       
    </div>
```

The hidden input is also necessary.
Now the JS code has to look something like this:-

```
$(function () {
    $('#dropdown').change(function () {
        var value = $('#dropdown').val();
        alert(value.length);
        var index = (new Date()).getTime();
        var clone = $('#showInvestmentForm').clone();

        clone.html($(clone).html().replace(/\[#\]/g, '[' + index + ']'));
        clone.html($(clone).html().replace(/"%"/g, '"' + index + '"'));
        $('#field1').append(clone.html());
    });
```

DateTime is for producing random index numbers. The `[#]` is replaced by those randomly generated DateTime values.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I cannot comment yet, so I'll post this as an answer (which it might actually be).

The problem you described occurs when "value.length" of the dropdown selection is greater than 1 (thus multiple textboxes were being created).

Taking this snippet out of your code:

```
else if (value.length > 1) {
   for (var i = value.length; i <= value.length ; i++) {
      $(form1).appendTo('#field1');
   }
}
```

..we can see that there's an unwanted behavior regarding DOM manipulation - essentially, **creating multiple elements with the same ID**.

I am guessing since you are probably listening to those textboxes changes using an ID, you will experience exactly the problem you described.

A little snippet that might help:

```
else if (value.length > 1) {
   for (var i = value.length; i <= value.length ; i++) {
      var newTextBox = document.createElement('div');
      newTextBox.innerHTML = form1.innerHTML;
      newTextBox.setAttribute('id', 'textbox'+i);
      $(newTextBox).appendTo('#field1');
   }
}
```

(Not sure this will actually work since I don't have enough info, but the idea should fix the problem)

Comment: Yes,it's producing textboxes with the same ID.How will I be able to produce textboxes with indexing? :| Can you point me to the right direction?

Comment: I can try. A possibility is to duplicate the HTML, creating a new element with a different ID (based on the loop's index, or whatever) and then append that new element. You will obviously have to change your listening functions to know how to handle that dynamic assignment. I'll add a snippet to the answer.

Comment: Thank You.This helped a lot :) I am still working on what I need but this was really helpful.